# Java JSP SpringMVC: Trouble making table cells editable

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, spring-mvc

**Goal**

I have a table of data (just text) that is retrieved when the jsp page loads. I'm trying to make the cell, currently containing text, turn into a textbox, with that text in it, if it is clicked on. There is an "Update" and "Delete" button at the end of each row. Update will pass whatever text the row currently has to the controller's update method (working fine). Delete will pass the key (whatever cell in that row that I designate as the key) to the controller's delete method (not working due to issue #2). I don't have any issues with the controller class, spring, or anything other than the JSP and JavaScript front-end.

**Problem**

(All of these problems would be solved with an up-to-date example project that allows in-place editing, deletion, and insertion of table rows in an *HTML table* with *bare-minimum* JavaScript. I've read through so many examples, which either create the table with 100% JavaScript/jQuery/jTable/etc, or use an HTML table, but without the basic functionality I described.)

1. I can't figure out how to make a cell containing text, turn into an input textbox with that original text inside it. I can either display a cell with text, or a cell with a textbox containing the original text, but not both interactively. I've tried different JS examples which all had issues I was unable to resolve, mainly because they were written for some other, slightly similar purpose.
2. I can't figure out how to make two different forms and their respective submit buttons act on the same data. I have a form for each row, and two submit buttons at the end of the row, "Update" and "Delete". I can only have one of them working at a time because I don't know of any way to associate one submit button with update, while associating another button, "Delete", with a form that performs the delete action.
3. As you will see in the controller code, for some reason, I have to have
   `model.addAttribute("row", myService.retrieveRecords().get(0));` in the controller even though this call: `model.addAttribute("records", myService.retrieveRecords());` already populates each row. I don't understand how to accomplish the same thing without that extra line of code.
4. I can't figure out how to have a row of empty textboxes at the bottom of the table that can be used for adding new rows to the table. I tried duplicating the way rows are currently displayed (as textboxes), just with empty values, but Java was complaining that the path variables in `<td><form:input path="cell1" value="${row.cell1}"/></td>` were identical to the new, blank row I created.

**Current Code**

**JSP**

```
<body>
<div align="center">
    <table border="1" cellpadding="5">
        <caption><h2>TABLE</h2></caption>
        <tr>
            <th>CELL1</th>
            <th>CELL2</th>
            <th>CELL3</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach var="row" items="${records}">        
            <tr>
                <form:form class="data-form" method="post" action="updateRow" modelAttribute="row">
                    <td><form:input path="cell1" value="${row.cell1}"/></td>
                    <td><form:input path="cell2" value="${row.cell2}"/></td>
                    <td><form:input path="cell3" value="${row.cell3}"/></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="UPDATE"/></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="DELETE"/></td>
                </form:form>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
```

**Controller**

```
// "C".R.U.D.
@RequestMapping(value = "/addRow", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String handleCreateRecordRequest(@ModelAttribute("record") TodoListRecord record, Model model) {
    myService.createRecord(record);
    return HOME_PAGE_REDIRECT;
}

// C."R".U.D.
@RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET) // 
public String handleRetrieveRecordsRequest(Model model) throws IOException {
    // This has to be in here or it complains that row is null, even though records populates row...     
    model.addAttribute("row", myService.retrieveRecords().get(0)); 
    model.addAttribute("records", myService.retrieveRecords());
    return HOME_PAGE;
}

// C.R."U".D.
@RequestMapping(value = "/updateRow", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String handleUpdateRecordRequest(@ModelAttribute("row") TodoListRecord row, Model model) {
    myService.updateRecord(row);
    return HOME_PAGE_REDIRECT;
}

// C.R.U."D".
@RequestMapping(value = "/deleteRow", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String handleDeleteRecordRequest(@ModelAttribute("key") String key, Model model) {
    myService.deleteRecord(key);
    return HOME_PAGE_REDIRECT;
}
```